# How to generate all k-sublists of a list in Java?

Tags: java, list, java-8

Let's consider:`List <String> ints = Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4","5","6")` and let `k=2`.

We would like to return following list `List<String> : ["12", "23", "34", "45", "56"]`

What about elegant solutions? Is it possible to do it with streams ?

Of course it can be solved in many ways, the simplest is iterating over whole list with nested list `1...k`.

Any ideas?

Comment: using streams to access several elements simuntaniously is not very elegant. why not iterating? its simple, easy to understand and easy to debug

Comment: is i.e. `"16"` also sublist?

Comment: It's possible and someone will probably post a convoluted solution. Standard Java 8 streams are not good for this, either don't use them or use a better stream library.

Comment: some ideas using stream instead of for loops http://www.deadcoderising.com/2015-05-19-java-8-replace-traditional-for-loops-with-intstreams/

Answer (score 4):

With Streams:

```
        final List<String> ints = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
        final int k = 2;
        final List<String> result = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1).limit(ints.size() - k + 1)
                .mapToObj(i -> ints.subList(i, i + k).stream().reduce("", (a, b) -> a + b + ""))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(result);3
```

With a for loop:

```
    List<String> result = new LinkedList<>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < ints.size() - k + 1; i++) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            sb.append(ints.get(i+j));
        }
        result.add(sb.toString());
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

Now decide yourself ;-)

Answer (score 4):

If you can live with a `Collection<String>` instead of a `List<String>` in your result, then you could use Java 9's [`Collectors.flatMapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-):

```
Collection<String> result = IntStream.range(0, ints.size() - k)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, 
        Collectors.flatMapping(i -> ints.subList(i, i + k).stream(), 
            Collectors.joining())))
    .values();
```

Another way, similar to [IEE1394's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47112058/1876620):

```
List<String> result = IntStream.range(0, ints.size() - k)
    .mapToObj(i -> String.join("", ints.subList(i, i + k)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Hi @Eugene! Thanks! I like the second one, but you know... I think I prefer a common imperative approach...

Comment: you could pass the result to `new ArrayList<>()`-constructor, to get a list back